# How do we know these are parademons?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In *Batman v. Superman*, Bruce Wayne has a crazy dream sequence out in the desert where he fights a bunch of soldiers. There are flying bat-like monsters in the dream.

I've seen a number of questions and answers here that refer to these as parademons as if that were obvious. Although I know who Darkseid is from TV shows, I've never read a comic involving him, and didn't know what parademons were when I saw the movie. To me, they looked like some crazy bat-monsters that made sense in Bruce's dream as some kind of psychological response to the guilt he's likely feeling due to all the recent violence. In other words, I interpreted it as Batman feeling like a monster, so his dream had bat monsters in it.

After seeing the reference to parademons on this site, I looked them up. The Wikipedia article has pictures that look nothing like the creatures in the movie. I did a Google image search for parademon, and I get a bunch of green-and-yellow-wearing humanoids with apparently mechanical wings.

**How do we know these are parademons? Is their appearance similar to the appearance of parademons in any particular comic or other medium?**

Comment: I guess my theory that Batman has PTSD from fighting in the Battle of Geonosis has been proven false.

Comment: @RogueJedi It's too bad though, it was a good theory.

Comment: When I rewatched the movie, I realized I was conflating the monster in the crypt dream sequence with the monsters in the desert dream sequence, leading to the recollection of them being batlike.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parademons are shocktroopers for the villain [Darkseid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkseid).

Now that I'm aware of the concept of a parademon, and have some idea what they look like in the comics, I've been going back and looking at screen caps of that dream sequence for comparison.

Now that I know what I'm looking for, they look less like bats, and more like insectoid parademons. Look at these pictures for comparison.

**Parademons from the New 52 Justice League re-launch:**

Note the goggles, the shape of the wings, and the armor. Also note the flying posture and the swarming.

[image: Comic Parademons]
<sub>(source: [denofgeek.us](http://cdn2.denofgeek.us/sites/denofgeekus/files/styles/insert_main_wide_image/public/3/35//justice-league-parademons.jpg?itok=l1uszAxh))</sub>

**Parademons in *Batman v. Superman*:**

From this close-up, you can see the resemblance.

[image: Parademon Up Close]

From this wide shot, you can see they are swarming and flying similarly.

[image: Parademon Swarm]

This close resemblance, combined with other clues related to Darkseid in the movie, such as the presence of a [mother box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box), makes it safe to conclude that these are parademons.

Comment: What's a "mother box"?

Comment: @AndresF. That's a good question, but probably outside the scope of this answer. There's a [Wikipedia article about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box). In short, they're "sentient, miniaturized, portable supercomputers". You see one in the movie when they show the scene with Cyborg.

Answer (score 17):

#### The hint that these creatures are parademons lies not just in the Knightmare Batman clip where they appear but in all of the other information given throughout the movie.

[image: Character in a dessert looking at a city]

> This dream sequence hints at the eventual existence of **[Darkseid](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Darkseid)**, but does not confirm it until the parademons are seen as a supporting military force. However, the giant Omega symbol on the ground is a trademark symbol of Darkseid, so much so, his signature power is called the Omega-beam. Modern depictions of the character have included the symbol on his armor.

[image: alleged parademons]

> The appearance of parademons varies widely, even their creator (Jack Kirby) was not consistent with their appearance. Overall, they are monstrous humanoids capable of flight, either using technology or in some versions via mutation. The flying part was the most important aspect since they were Darkseid's first shock-troop to open any battle. Armed with ranged weapons, terrifying speed and a degree of superhuman strength, they were the first enforcement Darkseid would drop to pacify an enemy force. Their swarming patterns, the picking up and carrying away of troops as well as their fast attack style is reminiscent of their appearances in the DC Universe. There are very few other known characters with this signature appearance. With the Omega symbol and their sudden appearance, it was a strong indicator of their existence.

[image: Scott Free and parademons]

*Scott Free attempting to escape parademons as envisioned by their creator, Jack Kirby.*

When parademons were not acting as shock-troops they would also be employed as jailers or hounds tracking citizens of Apokolips who broke rules, committed crimes or tried to escape the planetwide surveillance of Apokolips. They would be provided as support troops for ground operatives backing up those troops with uncompromising air power.

Parademons will only obey strong leaders and rarely have moral problems as long as their leaders are visibly kicking butt. Should their leaders lose or they find themselves taking casualties, they have been known to abandon such leadership and escape via Boom Tube.

[image: Steppenwolf on a battlefield]

> *Steppenwolf, one of Darkseid's major generals in the New 52 reboot.*

They would often be lead by a leader whose power would be the equal of any member of the Justice League. Beings such as Kalibak or Steppenwolf, whose fighting capacity equals or exceeds that of Superman or Wonder Woman, would make this invasion force almost unbeatable.

[image: flying parademons]

> *Batman v. Superman* has made enough of an effort to hint at the existence of Darkseid, both through the dialogue ("The dinner bell has been rung, he is coming...") as well as through their visuals (released in the movie during the dream sequence as well as in later unreleased footage) showing a being likely to be Steppenwolf or some other clearly alien being in possession of what would appear to be Mother or Father Boxes.

Comment: Hello sir, may I know how do you get all these relevant images so quickly? How do you search for the right comics, are these images from your database of google itself??

Comment: Honestly, I'm not very impressed by this answer. It wouldn't have done much of anything to convince me at the time I wrote the question. The one picture of parademons you have from the movie is basically the same one I already have (the wide shot that doesn't actually show the resemblance), and you haven't made it clear how any of the other stuff is related.

Comment: @ABcDexter, I write on superheroes all the time. I am one of the more well known writers on Superheroes, their identities, enemies and histories on the Stack. I also write on Quora.com so I end up with most of these images already available to me because I have usually written about them before. One of the advantages I have is I have been reading comics for 40 years so I have most of the information in my head and I only have to scour my image database or online repositories. When nothing else will do, I scan it myself.

Comment: @DCShannon, I am less concerned with impressing you, per se, as I am with providing information which I have already confirmed with other sources besides my own. You are free, of course, to go out into the interent, ask other comic sources and they will eventually point you back to where you are now, with information that these are in fact, most likely Parademons, since the story resembles a New52 saga which has recently been released as well as several other stories written over the history of the DC universe. I am certain others will answer the question for you as well.

Comment: Uh.. what? I'm not disagreeing with any of your conclusions. They completely agree with mine. There's no need to defend them. I'm criticizing your presentation of that information. For instance, I imagine you included that first picture because of the Omega symbol, but you don't actually make that connection in the answer. I only know that's related to Darkseid because of the research I did earlier today.

Comment: That's significantly clearer, thanks. +1

Comment: Also note that the pillars of flame in the background of the Omega picture could very easily be Apokoliptic flame pits; that is what I immediately assumed they were when I saw the scene.

Comment: Exactly, THOSE ARE FIREPITS! I will make a proper notation and include a representative graphic.

Comment: It does look like the parademons hit the gym hard in that scene, specially when compared to the JLU cartoon